# Magento : Product Attributes Indexing Gets Infinitely Processing

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, product-attribute, reindex

In `System > Manage Indexes`, in the Product Attributes Index only, the processes does not get completed, even after compiling Magento several times. Even researching, I found nothing that could help me find the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-indexing from CLI in this case.

Use the following command to re-index everything:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```

Or, run this process only for a particular index:

```
php shell/indexer.php info
```

(to get the index-code you need)
and then for example:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
```

Usually there you will get further details about why a re-indexing process can not be completed.